# Prettier.js confic how to convert any js file in any subfolder

Tags: javascript, wildcard, eslint, prettier

I'm trying to run prettier for any js file inside the following folder:

```
prettier --config .prettierrc --write ./resources/assets/js/**
```

But it only converts the js files located into js folder. I would like to convert any js file in any subfolder inside `/assets/js/...`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `./resources/assets/js/**/*.js`?

Comment: This does exactly the same as my example, all the .js files inside first level folder after js.

Comment: You should list all the different formats you've tried, or you'll just end up with people saying *"try this", "try that"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

`prettier --write "./resources/assets/js/**{.js,}"`

And then I created an ignore file, that specifies any folders or file types that need to be ignored.

**.prettierignore**

```
resources/assets/js/vendor/
*.min.js
*.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prettier --config .prettierrc --write ./resources/assets/**/*.js
```

May be it helps you.

Comment: This does exactly the same as my example, all the .js files inside first level folder.